# Scroll to the last command on Terminal? (like OS X Terminal marks)

Tags: terminal, command, command-history, terminal-emulator

[Mac OS X Terminal *marks*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal) are incredibly useful.

For example, when I type a command that echoes a lot output, it's easy to read the beginning with <kbd>Cmd+Up</kbd>. It will scroll to the last command and highlight it, since there's the option *Automatically Mark Prompt Lines* and <kbd>Cmd+Up</kbd> will scroll to the last *mark*.

Is there any terminal emulator with this functionality? Or some plugin, whatever. How do you go fast to the last command, highlighting it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (apart from, of course, Mac OS X Terminal; and presumably iTerm2 with its shell integration having something quite similar). I find this a really useful idea and have filed an enhancement request for vte/gnome-terminal: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767230.

Comment: @egmont Thanks, it would be superb having it on GNOME Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

This is workaround - not a solution.

I run the [`reset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reset.1.html) command before a command with a long output. Something like

```
$ reset
$ cat some-long-file.txt
```

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> (in the [Xfce4 Terminal Emulator](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/terminal)) to scroll to the beginning of the terminal history.

The downside is that the previous terminal history is lost but sometimes it is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

VTE based terminals, such as e.g. GNOME Terminal, GNOME Console, Xfce4 Terminal, Terminator, Tilix, Guake and more, support jumping between prompts since the GNOME 46 (VTE 0.76) release in March 2024.

The hotkey is hardcoded for the time being, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Under the hood, VTE uses the quasi-standard OSC 133 shell integration escape sequences to see where the prompts are, like several other terminals already do.

There's no generic marks support yet, you cannot manually place such stopping points.

Comment: What needs to be done in the prompt for it to be recognized? On my Arch system, with `vte4 0.76.0-2` (used by GNOME Console `KGX 46.0 using VTE 0.76.0 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD`) and `vte3 0.76.0-2` (used by Terminator 2.1.3), Console jumps to the top and Terminator does nothing.

Comment: You need to `source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh` (or whatever the exact filename is) in your `bash` or `zsh`. That sets up the prompt. If you use a different shell then this script should guide you what to do. This should fix it in Console (if it jumps to the top then it means it simply didn't see any prompt).

Comment: In Terminator Ctrl+Shift+Arrows are configured by default to resize panes. You'll need to remove these shortcuts in its config, or e.g. move them to e.g. Ctrl+Alt+Arrows as in Tilix. This is something I should mention in my answer :)

Comment: Terminator: filed https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/897.

Comment: @muru I see on your profile that you use `zsh`. I wrote the zsh bits with hardly any experience with this shell. Maybe it doesn't play well with some of the things you already do with in your zsh configs. In that case feedback on making it more robust (yet keeping it reasonably simple in the mean time) would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on now. I'm using [a zshrc](https://grml.org/zsh/grmlzshrc.html) which sets `PS1` anew for each prompt (akin to using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set `PS1` in bash), so the modifications from `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` were lost. Using my prompt theme's customization options to add back `OSC 133;A ST`/`OSC 133;B ST` to the start and end, it started working in GNOME Console. Thanks for the pointer! I suppose, like with using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set `PS1` in bash, this is not something a maintainer would be reasonably expected to accommodate.

Comment: You're right, I don't think it's possible to 100% protect against further modifications of `PS1`, but even if it is, its complexity is probably not worth it for us. I think you have better chances of convincing `grml` folks to add these escape sequences (after all, they are _mostly_ the same in all supporting terminals).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the search feature of your terminal buffer. Press:

```
$ ctrl+shift+f
```

to enter search mode. Then type part (or all) of your last command and it scrolls back highlighting the search term. Press ESC key (escape) to get out of the search mode.