# Mac Command + Up arrow functionality in Linux terminals?

Tags: terminal

I really like the the Command + Up/Down arrow keyboard shortcut in Mac terminal. It jumps between user commands typed in the terminal.

Is there a similar function in linux terminals (like the GNOME terminal)?

**Note:** See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209907/31113 for the behavior that I am describing. Thanks to @user4556274 for pointing it out.

Comment: It appears this question is referring to the 'mark' functionality described in this SE question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal , not simply browsing through command history, as one might think on first read of the question as currently phrased.  (in particular, "Jumping Between Marks" in the accepted answer on that question)

Comment: @user4556274 Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out the correct name.

Comment: Same question and some information there (in the comment's link): [Scroll to the last command on Terminal? (like OS X Terminal marks)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287541/scroll-to-the-last-command-on-terminal-like-os-x-terminal-marks)